# viewDidAppear isn't getting called after running from the background

Tags: iphone, sdk, multitasking

Method `viewDidAppear` is not getting called after going from the background back into my iPhone Application.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I need to call a method every time my `MainViewController` is shown (even after returning from the background) that will change a label to the new date.

`viewDidAppear` doesn't seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is working properly.

Instead, consider installing a notification handler for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, whichever may be more appropriate for your situation. From there you could do an update of your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You will have the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification method in App delegate.Now you need to create the object of the class you want and call the viewwillAppear

this method will be called when the app is in background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}
```

now for the view will appear code like this

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ViewController *vc = [ViewController alloc]init];//you can use your viewcontroller here

    [vc viewDidAppear:YES];// this will call the method.
}
```

Comment: I would not call the viewController lifecycle methods (viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, etc.) from my code my self, in my opinion its bad practice. Better is to create a private method where you do you stuff and call this private method from the applicationWillEnterForeground and viewWillAppear methods

Comment: i had just suggested this because you have written that you r not supposed to call viewdidAppear, You can call any method in place of viewdidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewWillAppear if you dont mind doing this process before the is actually shown.
Else you can use the method.
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{}